# install OJDBC7 using maven POM file

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I have a project A that where i created  a folder called lib to add libraries in it. Currently i have Ojdb7.jar in this folder. Now, When I add the dependency for ojdbc7 in the POM file I get error "Missing artifacts".
I know there is an option to install it using :
$ mvn install:install-file -Dfile={Path/to/your/ojdbc7.jar} 
      -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
and it works fine when I run the command but What I want to do is to run mvn package command from cmd (mvn packge will run install before packaging the project to jar file). I tried the pom file below but i get error could not find artifact for the path I specified in repository tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>DarAppDemo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>DarAppDemo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>demo-local-repo</id>
        <name>demo-lib</name>
        <url>file:\\${project.basedir}\lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I found one solution by adding a plugin to build tag

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-ojdbc-jar</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${project.basedir}/ojdbc7.jar</file>
                        <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                        <version>12.1.0</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

but my issue is that i don't want to hard code this path ${project.basedir}/ojdbc7.jar
Because I run this in Jenkins and it failed. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

**Adding screen shot
[image]

Here another shot from eclipse Problems:
[image]

Comment: HI @mbn217 , please could you attach the log of your commands : mvn install & mvn package ?   nearly always it is an mvn install error, folder permissions, etc. If you can attach the -X in your mvn commands to extra log.

Comment: @jrichardsz I have attached a screen shot of  mvn --debug install. I dont think it help that much thought

Comment: the mvn install command move the jar to your /home/.m2 folder. I can see in your screenshot other folder. You cloud use https://gist.github.com/ to share your mvn install and mvn clean package. Are you using  eclipse to execute the mvn clean package? if this is the case, sometimes eclipse, use another .m2 folder instead commandline mvn .m2 folder.   Also this is a maven question, not jenkins

Comment: I actually did try that before too but it didn't work. For some reason when i run clean package , it's not installing that jar because its not reading the path correctly.

Comment: execute mvn -X and show us the result. Are you using commandline or eclipse to run your commands?

Comment: im using command line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176288/discussion-between-jrichardsz-and-mbn217).